# Will constructor chaining create more than one object in Java?

Tags: java, this, constructor-chaining

If I am calling another constructor of same class using this keyword. Will it create two objects?

If so, which object will be active in below example:

```
Class Sample {
    int a;
    String b;

    Sample() {
        this("Hello");
        a=10;
    }

    Sample(String temp) {
        b = temp;
    }    
}
```

I want to know the behaviour of Constructor chaining. Please explain how it works?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, constructor chaining doesn't create an additional instance, it just executes the logic of the chained constructor, allowing you to reuse its code.

Comment: Thanks for you input. So, this means, it is same as calling another method.

Comment: @user3232754 It's not exactly the same. The call to the other constructor must be the first line in your constructor, and the other constructor calls the super class's constructor implicitly. Also, you can only make this call from a constructor. If it was like any other method, you could call it from any method.

Answer (score 2):

**No**,
`this("Hello");` here ll call `Sample(String temp)` constructor, it won't create another object.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned you'll get just one object, with each constructor initialising the same object.

Best to see for yourself:

```
public class Sample {
    int a;
    String b;

    Sample() {
        this("Hello");
        a=10;
        System.out.println("B: "+ hashCode());
    }

    Sample(String temp) {
        b = temp;
        System.out.println("A: "+ hashCode());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sample();
    }

}
```

Note that calling instance methods on a not fully initialised object may cause issues if you try to access uninitialised fields so tread carefully.